# Proving that a singleton set is both open and closed inside this metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space and let $a \in E$.

Let $\delta(x,y)=\begin{cases} d(a,x)+d(a,y) & x \neq y \\ 0 & x = y \end{cases}$.

It can be proved that $\delta$ is a metric on $E$ (I did that).  Let $x_{0}$ belong to $E$. Prove that $\{x_0\}$ is open and closed in $(E,\delta)$.

Comment: What balls around $x_0$ contain no other points do you think?

Comment: consider [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) next time you ask a question.

Comment: how can $X_0$ be an element in $E$ and be a subset of it at the same time ?

Comment: fyi,  this leads to the discrete metric, in which every set is clopen

Comment: @Alan not quite. It's possible that $a$ has no ball around it which is a singleton. For instance if $E$ is the real line, the ball around $a$ of radius $r$ contains all points $t$ such that $|a-t|<\frac{r}{2}$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I think you misunderstood a key aspect of this site. This is more about *helping* you find the right answer then giving you answers to arbitrary problems. For example, if you were to give us what you've tried, where you've looked, what you've read to answer the problem, and describe why you aren't satisfied/doubt what you've come across, I'm sure others would help. Also, choosing a descriptive title that described the content would help. For more, I recommend reading [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9754)

Answer (score 1):

Show that for all $x\in E\setminus\{a\}$, there is a radius $r_x$ such that the ball $B_{r_x}(x)=\{x\}$. Conclude that $\{x_0\}$ is open, and that $E\setminus\{x_0\}$ is open.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: Which part do you think needs more explanation? I was purposely vague so that you might try and fill in the gaps.

Comment: how can i prove that it is closed? (i could prove that its open) @Daniel Rust

Comment: Try covering $E\setminus\{x_0\}$ with a load of open balls (you'll have to be a bit careful when it comes to covering $a$ but not $x_0$, but I think you should be ok if you remember the above hint.